# Finding number of iterations until certain value

Tags: numerical-methods, roots

we have fixedpoint iteration $x_{k+1} = 1 + e^{-x_k} $. I need to prove that that the iteration converges for any starting point $x_0\in [1,2]$ and determine its convergence rate and estimate the number of iterations it will take to achieve $10^{-5}$.

Let $g(x) = 1 + e^{-x}$ so we have scheme $x_{k+1} = g(x_k)$ We have $g'(x) = -e^{-x}$ and on $[1,2]$ $|g'(x^*)| < e^{-1} < 1 $ and so the iteration converges in that interval. Im stuck on the second part. By definition, the convergent rate of an interation is given by

$$ \lim \frac{ |E_{k+1}| }{|E_k|^r } = C $$

where $E$ is the error and $C> 0$ is constant. In our case,

$$ |E_{k+1}| =| x_{k+1} - x^*| = |g(x_k) - g(x^*)| < g'(\xi )|x_k-x^*|<|E_k| $$

since $g'(anything) < 1$ So

$$ \frac{ |E_{k+1} |}{|E_k|}  < 1 $$

So $r=C=1$ can we conclude then that the rate of convergence is linear? how do we find the number of iteration to achieve $10^{-5}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rate of convergence is certainly linear because $g(x)$ can be approximated by a linear function when $x$ is very close to $x^*$.  You have already written that $|E_{n+1}|=|x_{n+1}-x^*|=|g'(\xi)||x_{n}-x^*|$, where $\xi\in[x_n,x^*]$ or $\xi\in[x^*,x_n]$. Rate of convergence can be calculated in the following way:
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{|E_{n+1}|}{|E_{n}|}=\lim_{\xi\to x^*}{|g'(\xi)|}={x^*-1}.
$$
(Note that $g'(x^*)=-e^{-x^*}=1-x^*$)

The number of iteration needed to reach an error of $10^{-5}$ depends on the starting point(if you start with $x^*$ then NO iteration is needed!). But let's suppose that $x_0=2$. Then $|E_0|$ is less than $1$. We can check that $x^*<1.28$. So $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{|E_{n+1}|}{|E_{n}|}<0.28$ for large $n$ in general. So we want to have $0.28^n<10^{-5}$. This means $n>9$. So about a dosen iterations are needed.

Comment: how do we find the number of iterations until achieve $10^{-5}$?

Comment: @Neymar Wait a moment. I am checking it

Comment: I dont see why $(0.28)^n < 10^{-5}$

Comment: If $0.28^n<10^{-5}$, then we can be almost sure that $E_n<0.28^n E_0<10^{-5}$. (Approximately only.)

Comment: are you taking $E_0=1$?

Comment: @Neymar We know that $E_0\leq 1$